# Inserting blank line in csv using java

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I want to insert a blank line in csv using java. I have written following code:

```
CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator("\n").withEscape('\\');
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(csvFile);

CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter,csvFileFormat);

csvFilePrinter.printRecord("data1");
csvFilePrinter.printRecord("\n");
csvFilePrinter.printRecord("data2");
```

When I open this generated CSV in notepad++, I am getting 2 blank lines:

```
 data1
 " 
 "
 data2
```

How can I get a single blank line?

Comment: A single blank line between data   is not valid CSV. How would you parse that?

Comment: And don't think of that output as "two blank lines", you're getting one "Record" that's a newline character surrounded by quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try <s>`csvFilePrinter.printRecord("");`</s> `csvFilePrinter.println();` `printRecord` will escape the line automatically. You do not need an additional escape character.

Comment: This would still put two quotes on a single line, no?

Comment: Yes.. "" are still present at the blank line

Answer (score 3):

[`printRecord`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#printRecord-java.lang.Iterable-) prints a record separator after the data, in this case a newline.

Then you print a newline which is printed as a string containing another newline, which gives you those two double quotes on separate lines.

Just remove the one that prints a newline or, if you really want that empty line, use [`csvFilePrinter.println()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#println--) which will output the record separator (in your case, `"\n"`).

Comment: Removing it doesn't create a single blank line in the output, as asked, though

Comment: `CSVFormat` has an option to ignore blank lines though

Answer (score 1):

I guess replacing `csvFilePrinter.printRecord("\n");` with `csvFilePrinter.println();` does the job.
[`println()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#println--) will output lines separator, so you will get completely empty line without quotes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This would still put two quotes on a single line, no?

Comment: This worked.. But as @cricket_007 said I am getting following output:      data1 "" data 2

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni, I've updated my answer after your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You define the CSVFilePrinter with

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator("\n")
```

so for each record an additional `\n` will be appended. You then print three records: "data1", "\n", "data2"

This will results in "data1\n\n\ndata2\n", which is exactly the result you get.

Just replace the second record with "".

Comment: I agree with your logic. I have 1 question. Why " is displayed at those blank lines?

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni You're right, I can't explain that. I thought that you just wanted to emphasize the empty lines. Is it a single double quote (") or two single quotes ('')? In the latter case, this might be to denote an empty value